# php mysql select statement; Not getting the output

Tags: php, mysql

I want to out put from a database the total sms sent from an application.

In this manner: `date 2016-06-09 | total sent 4 | delivered 3 | failed 2|`

```
| date       | total_sent | delivered | failed |
+------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| 2016-06-09 |          4 |         3 |      1 |
+------------+------------+-----------+--------+
```

However my code in php does not work. Some one please lead me...

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DATE(time_sent) AS date,COUNT(*) as total_sent,SUM(status = 'Success') as delivered,SUM(status = 'failed') AS failed FROM smsdb GROUP BY DATE(time_sent) ");

$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
$time_sent = $resultarr['time_sent'];


echo $time_sent;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/14067623#14067623

Comment: I edited the question. Kindly see. @CD001

Comment: have you tried to run query in mysql application? phpmyadmin for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make $sql variable a string:
$sql = "SELECT DATE(time_sent) AS date,COUNT(*) as total_sent,SUM(status = 'Success') as delivered,SUM(status = 'failed') AS failed FROM smsdb GROUP BY DATE(time_sent) ";

The second parameter for mysqli_query must be a string : http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.query.php

*EDIT*

You want the value of time_sent, but in your $resultarr you don't have that key as you have renamed it to **date** in your mysql query: **DATE(time_sent) AS date**. The keys of your array are: 'date', 'total_sent', 'delivered' and 'failed'. Try this: $time_sent = $resultarr['date'];

Comment: Thank you for the help. However the select statement works as required, I have checked it from the command line.                     $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);                                               
$resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
$time_sent = $resultarr['time_sent'];


echo $time_sent;                                                                                   Is the part I don't understand how to frame it. Thank you

Comment: Hello there. When I try $time_sent = $resultarr['date']; ..... I only get the date and no other fields like total number __ delivered ___ or failed ___. Kindly...

Comment: Sorry, I think I have fixed it. Thank you @mihaela